# Approximate cost of making a shell company

Tags: united-states, taxes, small-business, business, private-company

[Hi. I was thinking about making a company to hide a plane I am thinking of buying.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/64742/is-there-a-way-to-hide-your-name-from-registration?noredirect=1#comment168151_64742)

A helpful person suggested to make a shell company since planes can be registered to companies and FAA site doesn't show company owners.

I just want to keep people from learning my identity through N number of the aircraft. I am not thinking about money laundering nor drug running.

Lets assume we are in Texas. How much money I roughly need and how much taxes are needed to keep the company alive. I am thinking about asking the company anonymity part at the Legal.SE but I'd appreciate it here too.

The plane costs $300,000.

Comment: You're thinking about buying an airplane for $400K through a small company you'd set up, and you're concerned with the cost of setting up the company?

Comment: @aCVn future planning. A five year old second hand https://www.aircraft24.com/singleprop/maule/m9-235--xi129264.htm sells for 215K but I am worried about inflation and supply and demand in the industry. So lemme edit it to 300K

Comment: I doubt $300K or $400K makes any substantial difference to the answer; the cost is still likely to be in aquiring the airplane, not in setting up the company.

Comment: Also, "Let's assume we are in Texas" rhymes rather poorly with the claim in your profile that you're in Turkey.

Comment: @aCVn I am thinking about moving (I have a family with connections and I have a nice future education plan) and since every states have different taxes etc I decided Texas.

Comment: *"I am thinking about moving"* Fair enough.

Comment: Completely off-topic, but note that Texas has no _income_ tax but has higher than average _property_ taxes to compensate. Obviously you can save by living in a cheaper house, but be aware of that before making a final decision.

Comment: @DStanley what if I decide to live in a RV park and make the mail address be pinned on a "business associate" ? The biggest problem would be finding someone willing to give his mail address (and not asking huge cost) I guess.

Comment: You better call Saul.

Comment: But I dont know his number... "Seinfield Theme Plays"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get what you pay for.

The more you want to hide the connection the more expensive the setup. If you setup a shell corporation, but use as a mailing address an address that is associated with you, finding the connection is trivial.

The more you are willing to pay, the more complete the masking is.

Answer (score -1):

Google it.  You can setup an LLC in your state by yourself or thru an attorney.  You may also consider setting up an LLC or corporation in another state, if there are any benefits in doing so.  Good luck.